# blending smoothies in a metal pot - will the vitamins go away?

Tags: pot, smoothie, hand-blender

I do not own a professional mixer where you can put all your fruits in and start to blend. I am using a hand blender. I put all the fruits and some yogurt in the metal pot and then blend it all. Someone told me that the fluid is reacting with the metal/alluminium surface which destroys all the Vitamins. If this is true is there something I can do about it? First I have thought to use a plastic bowl instead but then I thought the metallic blades of the mixer will still affect the Vitamins. Is there any alternative to prepare Smoothies where no metals are involved?

Comment: Professional blenders also typically have metal blades, so your immersion blender does not differ there.

Answer (score 6):

I could not find (quick search) a reference to the fact that using a metal bowl "destroys" vitamins.

Aluminum bowls will react to some ingredients, mostly acidic ones (tomatoes, citrus..), but in a normal usage (blending fruits) , it should not be a problem.

Stainless steel bowls are NON reactive, and can be used with all ingredients, and usually sturdy enough to handle your hand blender.

You could use a glass bowl (tempered) or a plastic bowl.

Professional blenders (vitamix, blendtec, ... ) use either a glass bowl or a plastic bowl.